# Using StringBuilder.Append() in a lambda expression is producing an empty string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, stringbuilder

I'm trying to append a list of strings(> 10),so to avoid creating a lot of strings I am using a StringBuilder.It would be great if someone explains why this is happening..

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lst = new List<string>(){"A", "B", "C"};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        lst.Select(str => sb.Append(str.ToLower()));
        Console.Write("Output: {0}", sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Run the code here-dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wJ8rKU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been noted in other answers, the laziness of `Select` is the problem here. I'd add that more broadly, using side-effects (such as appending to a `StringBuilder`) is generally a bad idea within a LINQ query. Each selector, condition etc should ideally be side-effect-free.

As Gilad pointed out, you can use `string.Concat` in this case - but you'll need to use `Select` to convert each value to lower case, unless you want to do that after the fact (which may have a different result in some corner cases, I suspect).

So either:

```
var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
string result = string.Concat(list.Select(str => str.ToLower()));
```

Or, with a possibly different result, but creating fewer strings:

```
var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
string result = string.Concat(list).ToLower();
```

Given the existence of `string.Concat`, I wouldn't start using a `foreach` loop or `List.ForEach` etc... there's no need to do this "manually" when it's built into the framework.

You might also want to consider using `ToLowerInvariant` instead of `ToLower`, depending on exactly what you're trying to do. Casing is surprisingly complicated.

Comment: @GiladGreen: I'm tempted to try to find an example where lower-casing the concatenation output has a different result to lower-casing before concatenation, but I'm not *quite* sure it's worth it.

Comment: `str.ToLower()` instead of `str.Lower()`

Answer (score 2):

LINQ method `Select` is [lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-to-xml).
So, `lst.Select(str => sb.Append(str.ToLower()));` does not change `sb`

To see efeects, you must iterate throgh result:
`lst.Select(str => sb.Append(str.ToLower())).ToArray();` for example.

From @thehennyy:

You also can use method `List.ForEach`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ForEach` instead of `Select`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lst = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    lst.ForEach(str => sb.Append(str.ToLower()));
    Console.Write("Output: {0}", sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Or you could just use LINQ `Aggregate`:

```
var lst = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
string result = lst.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y).ToLower();
```

Comment: You can also aggregate into a StringBuilder :) `StringBuilder result = lst.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, str) => sb.Append(str));`

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda In the accepted answer is stated that appending to a StringBuilder is generally a bad idea within a LINQ query, so the second part of my answer supposed to be an alternative to StringBuilder, but thanks for the info anyway

Comment: yeah, but it's a different case. We aren't making a query and aren't causing observable side-effects. Each `.Append` returns a new StringBuilder reference passed as a new state for the callback, so it's quite a fair use of `.Aggregate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `.Aggregate` your strings into a builder -- using the fact that each `.Append` returns a new `StringBuilder` reference.

```
StringBuilder result = lst.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, str) => sb.Append(str));
```

This way you are not abusing the `.Select` iterator and aren't causing side-effects with the query.